# Should we say "they are high enough as they are" or "they are high enough as it is."?

Tags: idioms, grammatical-number, personal-pronouns, dummy-it, pronominal-agreement

I've heard on TV: "We really hope property taxes won't be increased; they are high enough as they are."  Would it be ungrammatical to say "...they are high enough as it is."?

Comment: They're both *grammatical*, but *idiomatically*, native speakers invariably use *[noun] is/are [adjective] enough **as it is*** in all such contexts.

Comment: @Fumble While it’s true that _as it is_ is certainly far more common, I have heard non-generic pronouns used in the expression more than just a handful of times from native speakers, too, and I would not bat an eyelash at using one myself, either; so I don’t really think your “invariably” is quite justified. “Normally”, yes, but not quite invariably.

Comment: @Janus: I don't want to split hairs over exactly how often something needs to happen before it *invariably* happens. But I've no reason to doubt Google Books figures - [*they're bad enough as it is*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22they%27re+bad+enough+as+it+is%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl):54 hits, [*they're bad enough as they are*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22they%27re+bad+enough+as+they+are%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl):7 hits. In my context, I'm happy to use *invariably* to describe such a preference.

Comment: @FF 'Invariably' here is just plain wrong, and you need to retract it. As you really believe, judging by the normal quality of your posts. If you wish, I'll mention that the ratio of Google hits for "they are high enough as it is" to "they are high enough as they are" is less than 5 : 1, as I'd certainly expect from personal experience. I'll delete this when appropriate.

Comment: @Edwin: When I use the word, I invariably mean something is a [*strong possibility without certainty*](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110625022910AAY7Apq).

Comment: @FF [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/invari), [AHDEL, Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/invariably), [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/invariably), [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/invariably), Google Dictionary ... all disagree, licensing only the strict 'always, on every occasion, at all times, without fail, without exception' sense. Nobody could claim that 80% of the time is 'invariably', even with Macmillan's looser second sense. Your use of 'invariably' here is wrong; in general it is unnecessarily unclear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that would be perfectly fine. The two phrasings mean *basically* the same thing, but with a difference in what you’re talking about.

When you say *as it is*, the subject *it* is a generic ‘it’ that refers vaguely to ‘the current situation’ or something like that. It could be rephrased to “the way things currently stand” or “in the current state of things”.

When you say *as they are*, the subject *they* refers back to the taxes and is therefore non-generic: it has a specific, concrete antecedent in the previous clause. It could be rephrased to “at the level they are currently at” or “in the state they are currently in”.

While it is theoretically possible to make this same distinction with a singular antecedent as well, there is no real way to carry out the distinction in practice, since you’d end up with *it* both with the generic, antecedent-less pronoun and with the specific antecedented one:

> I hope the income tax won’t be increased; it’s high enough as it is.

If the antecedent is a different pronoun, it becomes possible to distinguish again:

> I hope he doesn’t win—he’s big-headed enough as [he/it] is!

But in the end, the difference between the two is negligible enough that I doubt anyone would ever bat an eye or even notice in any context regardless of which option you use.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't.

Comment: A Google search for "bad enough as it is" gives 215 000 hits; one for "bad enough as they are" 171 000 hits. I haven't bothered filtering out false positives, but I'm happy enough that this reflects my perception of the interchangeability of the two variants. The data strongly suggests that 'While it’s true that _as it is_ is certainly far more common' is inaccurate, and 'native speakers invariably use [noun] is/are [adjective] enough as it is in all such contexts' just plain wrong.